# different "step" values for different handles in jquery slider with multiple handles

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider

I have a slider with 4 handles. The slider is for choosing the day start time, lunch start time, lunch end time and day end time.

Handle A can move in 15min steps. (9:15, 9:30, etc.)
Handle B should move in 30 min steps from handle A. (If A is set to 9:15, B should only slide to 9:45, 10:15, etc.
Handle C can move in 15min steps from Handle B
Handle D should again move in 30 min steps from handle C.

the slider is like this
Step:---15min-----------30min------15min------------30min-------
-----------|A|------------------|B|----------|C|----------------|D|----------------
----------9:00--------------12:00------13:30------------16:00

---

**A couple of valid slider state examples to clarify the question:**
-|A|-----------|B|-------------|C|-------------------|D|
9:15--------12:15---------13:00----------------15:00

-|A|-----------|B|-------------|C|-------------------|D|
9:30-------12:00---------13:00----------------16:30

---

Is there a way to set step as [15,30,15,30], like I set the values as [60, 240, 360, 540]?

Please help!
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve it using the start event of jQuery UI Slider. When you start to slide, identify the handle and update the step property of jQuery UI Slider.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="slider-range"></div>
</body>
```

Script:

```
 $(function () {
     $("#slider-range").slider({
         min: 0,
         max: 1500,
         values: [75, 300, 700, 1000],
         start: function (event, ui) {
             var hIndex = $(ui.handle).index();
             if (hIndex == 0 || hIndex == 2) {
                 $("#slider-range").slider("option", "step", 15);
             }
             if (hIndex == 1 || hIndex == 3) {
                 $("#slider-range").slider("option", "step", 30);
             }
         },
         slide: function (event, ui) {
             if (ui.values[0] > ui.values[1] || ui.values[1] > ui.values[2] || ui.values[2] > ui.values[3]) {
                 return false;
             }
             console.log("Handle 1:" + ui.values[0] + " 2:" + ui.values[1]+ " 3:" + ui.values[2]+ " 4:" + ui.values[3]);
         }
     });
 });
```

See the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wuBzN/39/)